# Delete Gmail account from 'my logins'

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I am gradually moving all of my accounts from all services to my iCloud account. This includes all my accounts from Stack Exchange.

My question is how do I remove my Gmail login for SE? I have made a new SE ID by using the 'my logins' setting. The only thing is how do I remove my Gmail account now I have set up the iCloud Stack Exchange ID?

**Edit:**

Here are my 'my logins' settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Click your username at the top of the page to go to your profile
2. Click the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab at the top
3. Click "My Logins" in the navigation menu on the left
4. Click "remove" next to the Open ID account you want to remove (Be sure you have a different Open ID account set up first)

You'll probably also want to log in to your [Google Account](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/ManageAccount) and revoke the Stack Exchange authorization from the "connected account".

Comment: How would I get a different Open ID. Do I all ready have one if I have both gmail and SE connected to the same account?

Comment: @iProgram you said "I have made a new SE ID ", that is an OpenID.

Comment: I know but is it a different OpenID to my gmail account or is it the same?

Comment: What do you have listed under "My Logins"? Maybe you should add a screen shot to your question.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Added in that ScreenShot for you. Would I still be able to keep all my accounts if I click 'remove' on my login account?

Comment: @iProgram: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. Remove the Google credentials; leave your iCloud credentials.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Thanks. I thought it was but I just wanted to confirm first. Wasn't sure if that would just be for this site. Thanks.